# « Il y a » avec ou sans « que »

Tags: indications-de-temps

> Il y a un an que j'habite ici.
>
> Il y avait une heure que je ne mangeais plus.
>
> Il y avait presque deux heures qu'elle était dans la salle d'attente.

**mais**

> Il y a un an on fêtait ses dix-huit ans.
>
> Il y vingt ans c'était une chose rare.

Pourquoi ces deux dernières phrase ne comportent-elles pas "que" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dans les premières phrases on peut remplacer "il y a" par "ça fait" sans que ça n'en change le sens. Ce n'est pas le cas pour les deux dernières.

Le premier sens donne donc une notion de temps. Le deuxième sens donne une notion d'existence de quelque chose, d'un fait.

Answer (score 2):

Intuitivement, je dirais que les deux phrases après le "mais" sont mal formées : il leur manque une virgule à chacune.

Il y a un an, on fêtait ses dix-huit ans (ou) Il y a un an qu'on a fêté ses 18 ans.

Il y a vingt ans, c'était une chose rare [sous-entendu : aujourd'hui, c'est banal].